# Web API Issue with FireBase.NET Library

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, firebase

On my C# based Web API I have implemented Google FireBase Push and can already send  push messages with Title and Body but when I try to add a Data payload into it, it is not accepting it. The error is:

Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary' to 'Firebase.NET.Contracts.IPayload'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)

This is my code.

SendFireBasePush.cs:

```
using System;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using Firebase.NET.Contracts;
using Firebase.NET.Messages;
using Firebase.NET.Notifications;
using Firebase.NET;
using System.Configuration;
// using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace SampleAPI
{
    public class SendFirebasePush
    {

        public async Task SFPExecute(string FireBasePushRegToken, string FireBasePushTitle, string FireBasePushBody, Dictionary<string, string> FireBasePushData)

        {

            string[] ids = {
                        //registration tokens here
                        FireBasePushRegToken
                    };

            var requestMessage = new RequestMessage
            {
                Body =
                        {
                            RegistrationIds = ids,
                            Notification = new CrossPlatformNotification
                            {
                                //Title = "Message Received:",
                                Title = FireBasePushTitle,

                                // Body = "Check your Inbox.",
                                Body = FireBasePushBody,

                                Sound = "default"
                            },

                            /*
                            Data = new Dictionary<string, string>
                            {
                                { "leage", "UEFA" },
                                { "game", "Albania vs Kosovo" },
                                { "score", "1:1" }
                            }
                            */

                            // this part he doesn´t like and I am getting the mentioned error. Also creating a new dictionary described above doesn´t work.
                            Data = FireBasePushData

                        }
            };

            // securely pointing to Azure AppSettings
            var GoogleFirebasePushKey = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["GoogleFirebasePush_SampleAPI"];
            var pushService = new PushNotificationService(GoogleFirebasePushKey);
            var responseMessage = await pushService.PushMessage(requestMessage);

        }

    }
}
```

And this is what the FireBase.NET project suggests how to use their library:
https://github.com/UrimKurtishi/Firebase.NET

This is their code:
https://github.com/UrimKurtishi/Firebase.NET/blob/master/src/Firebase.NET/Contracts/IPayload.cs

What I am doing wrong? Any help is appreciated.

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried doing as the error says and casting the `Dictionary<string, string>` to the `Payload` type?

It seems that you just need to do the following:

```
Data = FirebasePushData as Payload // Safe
```

or

```
Data = (Payload)FirebasePushData // Unsafe
```